# How to write a compound IF statement checking two sets of two values

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I know the title is confusing, but I can't figure our how to word it properly. I'm trying to figure out how to properly format a compound conditional in an IF statement in Excel. It's for a school project that's due tomorrow.

I already have something like this

```
=if(AND(b152="oval.jpg",c152="q'")OR(AND(b152="triangle.jpg", c153="p'")), "Correct", "Incorrect")
```

In psuedocode I want it to run something like this:

```
if (b152=="oval.jpg" && c152=="q'") or (b152=="triangle.jpg", c153="p'"):
  print("YES!")
else
  print("False!")
```

I know I'm missing something here. My current excel code returns false even if the conditions are true. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2):

`OR` is a function in Excel, like `AND`. Try something like this:

```
=if(OR(AND(b152 = "oval.jpg", c152 = "q'"), AND(b152 = "triangle.jpg", c153 = "p'")), "Correct", "Incorrect")
```

Comment: +1. Just beat me to it. (You posted while I was formatting.) :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm a bit of a perfectionist, so people do that to me all the time. :)